# slick slider formular tab switch from one slide to another

Tags: slick.js

i'm using slick slider for a large formular. Each section is one slide.

```
<form>
<div class="form-slider">
  <div>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
     <input type="text" name="eins"><br>
     <input type="text" name="zwei">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
     <input type="radio" name="drei">Drei A <input type="radio" name="drei">Drei B<br>
     <input type="text" name="vier">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.form-slider').slick({
          dots: true,
          draggable: false,
          swipe: false,
          nextArrow: $('.btn_next'),
          prevArrow: $('.btn_prev'),
          adaptiveHeight:true,
          accessibility: false
   });
```

My Problem is now, that if the user use tab to switch from one to another input field, the slider doesn't slide well, it only slides half of the next div. I tried to turn off the tab-function (by adding  tabindex="-1" on each input) but this doesn't work on safari high sierra! and it's not really userfriendly.

Example: [https://www.accuro-funds.li/test/](https://www.accuro-funds.li/fragebogen_test/)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like an open issue - https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/792
 You may consider handling the tab-events of your own than relying on slick.